# make text uppercase or lowercase from JSON

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

Got a problem when I was making to capitalize dynamically. In my code I can capitalize any letters but it is not dynamic, The program should guess which letter should it capitalize. For example some text comes from JSON and there should be some comparing that checks texts letters and users inputted letters and then he should guess which letter he must capitalize. If there is some solution for this, Please tell me.

**Here is my code**

**index.html**

```
<textarea id="fieldId" class="textarea" style="resize: none" cols="30" row="2" ui-mask="{{typetext}}" ng-model="model" data-ng-trim="fasle" ng-trim="false" ng-focus="expression">
</textarea>
```

**script.js**

```
link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {
    controller.$parsers.push(function(inputValue) {
        var transformedInput = '';
        if (inputValue) {
            for (var i = 0; i < inputValue.length; i++) {
                if (i === 0 || i === 5) {
                    transformedInput += inputValue.charAt(i).toUpperCase();
                } else {
                    transformedInput += inputValue.charAt(i).toLowerCase();
                }
            }
        }
        if (transformedInput != inputValue) {
            controller.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
            controller.$render();
        }
        return transformedInput;
    });
})
```

**Controller**

```
app.controller('myController', ['$scope', '$document', function($scope, $document) {
    $scope.typetext = "Some Text";
    $document.on('keydown', function(e) {
        if (e.which === 8 && e.target.nodeName !== "INPUT") {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
}])
```

[Demo HERE](https://plnkr.co/edit/CgfgLgkmr85WHum1ReP4?p=preview)

Comment: What should you be the input/output expected?

Comment: Well, I will try to explain. some text comes from JSON and then that text should be compared to the input value one-by-one letter. For example the text is : "The teXt". When user types 't' it must be compared by the text which came from json, so programm should transform 't' to uppercase, than programm should allow user to type lower cases till X, than again comparing x lowercase with X uppercase if it is not equal, it should be Uppercased.